# Getting the coordinates of GlutSolid*

Tags: opengl, 3d, glut

I was wondering, I have an algorithm of mine that I want to test with a high poly-count model. (I'm using a hard coded cube and surface atm). I know you can draw objects with the GluSolid* commands.

But the problem is, for my alogrithm I need access to the coordinates of the triangles the object consists of. Is there an easy way to access these, or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's not really an easy way to obtain these coordinates as they are just sent to the GL when calling these functions (you might use transform feedback, but that is definitely too cumbersome for your purpose). But these primitives are actually quite simple. You can quite easily generate a sphere or cylinder mesh yourself. Or write a small function for reading a common 3d model format (OBJ is quite common and easy to read), so you can search the web for models or create test models with your favourite modeling software.

Comment: Yeah, I know that :). Was just wondering if it was possible, thanks!